# interpret reduced cost of all binary variables

Tags: binary

I have prepared and run a Linear Programming model in SAS. I  have some questions about the output that I can’t find answers to, and am hoping that someone can help.

My model contains the decision variables X1, X2 …………..X12, and all are binary. The model minimizes cost of inputs on a weekly basis over a period of 7 weeks.

There are constraints that restrict use of specific inputs to no m ore than in 2 consecutive weeks, for minimum levels of effectiveness, and others. An example constraint for week 1 was

0.598X1-1 +0.585X2-1+0.435 X3-1+0.372X4-1 +0.479X5-1+0.63X6-1+0.678X7-1+0.648X8-1+0.631X9-1 +0.48X10-1+0.144X11-1+0.207X12-1 ≥ 0.5

Same as constraints for week2 …..week 7. X1-1 indicates pesticide 1 applied in week 1.

The objective function:  MinCost=  C  ∑*(i=1)^12▒∑*(j=1)^7  X(i-j)

In the solution, the variable summary from the SAS output is

```
                            Variable Summary
```

Variable name   Status      type       pric       Activity           Reduced cost

X1-1                      Binary      6.98          1                  1.12

X1-6                      Binary       6.98          1                  5.69

X7-7                      Binary       17.01         1                  11.15

X8-3                      Binary       12.95         1                  7.09

X8-4                      Binary       12.95         1                  7.09

X9-2                      Binary       1.44          1                  4.57

X9-5        Basi          Binary       1.44          1                    0

I picked the variables from the summary output that had the value ‘1' in the “activity column”. Only one of the variables has status of ‘basic’, the others apparently being non-basic by default. When  a variable is a  basic variable, it  is in the optimal solution, and its reduced cost is o. However, only one of these reduced costs is 0.

My question is

- does this output suggest an error in the program?
- if no, is this just the way that SAS presents output from the LP model?
- how do I explain and interpret these non-zero reduced costs for what appear to be basic variables?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You might have a better chance to get an answer if you improve the formatting. Especially the weird gray box character in the objective function is rather off-putting.